# DocuSign App Registering - Unable to add parameter part in callback URL

Tags: docusignapi

I facing some difficulty when registering app on DocuSign demo admin site. I am trying to add the callback URL with parameter part as http://myappurl/{parameter}/, but it denies to save with parameter part. It gives a message saying "The Integrator key could not be updated. Please try again in a moment". But if I remove the parameter part, it saves. I've done this some months ago without any problem, I was able to add the callback URL with parameter part, but facing this issue only recently. And also I see the Status of the app is greyed out (supposed to be in green color, I guess). Can somebody help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add {parameter} on an Integrator Key as DocuSign expects that it should be the exact URL which you will use as callback url when doing [Authorization Code Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html) or [Implicit Grant](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_implicit.html). I am not sure how you did it a few months ago because I have never seen it working with {parameter}. Also the status is greyed out if you are in Demo Account, once you promote your Integrator Key to Production [API Go Live Process](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live) then it will change the status to Green color with value as Live